What does e"e mean?
I was reading some 19th century minutes in the UK where it says

2 shillings to be paid by each e"e

This is from minutes documenting the regulations of a religious congregation.
What could e"e  mean?

I once worked at a company that did a bunch of HR-related business, and they frequently shortened "employee" to "ee" and "employer" to "er".

The above may well be correct, but can you provide a link, image, or reference? (My first thought in such cases is always "OCR error").

@StuartF It's handwritten and I am not allowed to take photographs. I will check if there actually were any employees.

Can we see some context, with a sentence before and after? Could help to know which e"e would be paying 2 shillings. It's common for jargon to use abbreviations.

It's clearly some kind of abbreviation. "employee" would be likely if it were a business, but probably not in a religious congregation. Are there any other long words in the minutes that begin and end with "e"?

You might get a better answer if you provide more context about what was being discussed in the minutes.

I’m just curious, why would a congregation’s regulations, or minutes of discussion thereof, be off limits to photograph?

@PaulTanenbaum the immediate reason seems to be that the owner of the records has forbidden it.  Whether there is an underlying reason, whether they are correct about that reason, and whether they have a right to prohibit photographs are of course different matters.

Simd: of what denomination is the congregation?  For what purpose is the sum of two shillings to be paid?  Perhaps that or some other context will help point someone to the solution.

This " is often used to mean 'ditto' from a similar previous line, especially if hand written, when it may align vertically.

I think it's clear here that e"e is non-standard and we need far more information. Because it's handwritten we can't even be sure that e"e is what is intended: it could simply be a " ditto symbol with a couple of ornaments. We really do need an image; but even without that, we need far more context.

Indeed, in a former trade I would write –"– or ~"~ etc. to ditto what was above, in lists I made in a professional capacity.
